# Bypassing Dashboard extension confirmation in chromium based browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I added one dashboard extension to browser based on chromium project.
But after adding that extension as default extension I get this pop up
[Dashboard conformation for editing [image: pop-up]

I want to bypass this conformation popup window.

Comment: Chromium by default shows such message. AFAIK, it can only be changed by modifying the source code, not sure if there's policy to bypass it. Maybe Google can help you

Comment: I tried to explore source code that contains such type of function like "add extension" popup which can be bypassed but was unable to find a related function for this specific popup

Comment: There's no way to bypass a built-in check generally, but there's one exception for simple extensions that don't require permissions or content script, [here's the list](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/ui/extensions/extensions_overrides/simple_overrides.cc) of allowed keys.

Comment: @wOxxOm These files are for an override rule of adding extensions from the web store but not with the build itself. It basic requirement that any extension must have.

Comment: If I understand your objection correctly, it sounds like an idea of how the browser should behave. In that case you can express it in https://crbug.com.